# Google maps cant change between types

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have two map types, one is a roadmap and one is a custom one.
When I change the typeMapId of the map and when I zoom in and out while its selected, it shows the custom map for a second but than it shows the roadmap above it.

If I put the opacity of the roadmap as 0.1 I can see the custom map.
I did a map.overlayMapTypes.push(custom) I will always see the custom map above the roadmap no matter what typeMapId is selected.
in the network tab i see that it gets the custom map first and then the roadmap.

// mapOptions

```
var mapOptions = {
    ...
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [ "default_map", "custom" ]
    }
}
```

// Adding the custom map

```
var custom_opts = {
    getTileUrl: ...,
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256,256),
    maxZoom: 24,
    minZoom: 3
}

var custom = new google.maps.ImageMapType(custom_opts);
custom.projection = new FlatProjection();
map.mapTypes.set("custom", custom);
```

// Switching between the types

```
if (self.customShown) {
    map.setMapTypeId("flatMap");
    self.customShown = false;
}
else {
    map.setMapTypeId("custom");
    self.customShown = true;
}
```

What can I do to make them change and see the current selected type above the other type? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's `"flatMap"`, shouldn't that be `map.setMapTypeId("default_map");`

Comment: The map type must exist as @duncan pointed out. +Check my answer for how to call it.

Comment: tbh im changing the map server from an old one and this part was already there. it worked before i changed the server, it doesnt work if i put in default_map or roadmap

Comment: when i look at map.mapTypes it has custom and flatmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

```
var mapType = "custom";
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId[mapType]);
```

Comment: it doesnt find the custom one

Comment: Then please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question so that we can recreate the issue and test.